# Problems in connecting with SQL Server using node js?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server, node.js

I am trying to connect to a remote sql server database which is hosted in a remote server using node js. Now, I tried to connect to the same database using c# and everything works perfect but I tried the same thing with Node and I keep getting error logs. I am unable to understand if the problem is at my end or is it the problem with the server.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

var config = {
    userName: 'realm',
    password: 'friend',
    server: '172.10.3.22',

    options: {

        database: 'ElmaTest',
        instancename: 'SQL2014'
    }
};




var updateMember = function( username, password) {
    return sql.execute( {
        procedure: "updateMember",
        params: {

            firstName: {
                type: sql.NVARCHAR,
                val: username
            },
            lastName: {
                type: sql.NVARCHAR,
                val: password
            }
        }
    } );
};

function  connecttoDb() {

  //  updateMember("elma","pass1234");
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log("message" + err);


    });


}

module.exports.datavalue = connecttoDb();
```

Error logs:- 
Example app listening at http://:::8081
messageConnectionError: Failed to connect to 172.10.3.22:1433 - connect ECONNREF
USED 172.10.3.22:1433

The thing is that the same connection string works with c# but refuses to work with Node js.

C# connection string:

```
<add name="ElmaReport" connectionString="Data Source=172.10.3.22\SQL2014;Initial Catalog=ElmaTest;User ID=realm;password=friend" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: are both c# and nodejs trying to connect **from** the same computer? and c# is using TCP connection?

Comment: @JaromandaX:- Yes Both c# and node js were from the same computer.

Comment: and c# is definitely using TCP - i.e. you have enabled TCP connections in MSSQL - and is MSSQL listening on port 1433

Comment: @jessica, have a look to my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to enable TCP connections, because these connections are disabled by default.

1)Open `Sql Server Configuration Manager`.

2)Expand `Sql Server Network Configuration`.

3)Click `Protocols for MSSQL`.

4)Change `TCP/IP` to `enabled`.

[image]

Comment: `SQLEXPRESS` - you're assuming the OP is using the **express** version, of course

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai:- Its already enabled. I checked it. Its still not working

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?